# WPF Window Transparency (including Non-Client Area)

Tags: wpf, transparency, opacity

Is there any way to make a WPF window transparent without losing the non-client area (borders, title bar, close/minimise/maximise buttons)?

Setting 'AllowsTransparency' to 'true' requires that 'WindowStyle' be set to 'None' (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254179/how-to-remove-the-non-client-area-of-a-wpf-window-without-using-allowtransparency)), which removes the non-client area.

One of the WPF developers [blogged about how transparent windows work in WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2008/09/08/transparent-windows-in-wpf.aspx), and why it would have been difficult to implement support for non-client area transparency.

> No matter what your window styles may suggest, transparent WPF windows do not have any visible non-client area.  This is fine for many scenarios where the intent is to create a custom window shape, but it can be annoying for people who just want to "fade in" a normal window.

A WPF-only solution, then, seems out of the question.

Calling the native [SetLayeredWindowAttributes function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633540(v=vs.85).aspx) and passing a WPF window's handle and LWA_ALPHA has no effect, as expected.

The only other approach I can think of is hosting WPF content within a Win32 (or possibly WinForms) window. I suspect trying to do this will result in [airspace issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688.aspx), however.

> WPF layered windows have different capabilities on different operating systems ...
>   WPF does not support transparency color keys, because WPF cannot guarantee to render the exact color you requested, particularly when rendering is hardware-accelerated.

I'm not sure if I'm reading the above correctly, but it sounds like trying to host WPF content featuring transparency is not possible.

Any ideas?

[image: Transparent Notepad2 Window]

Answer (score 2):

You can customize non-client area using library from ms called [WPF Chrome](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/chrome). Check this article: ['Custom Window Chrome'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx).

With this library you can make chrome transparent and change many more things.

Comment: I don't think this library provides any mechanism for making the standard window chrome transparent. I'd like to avoid being responsible for the non-client area and leave that up to the DWM.

Answer (score 2):

[Fluidkit](http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/) has an implmentation of a glass window, which I think is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks. The FluidKit GlassWindow implementation looks pretty good, and would let me set the window opacity as the non-client area is removed/replaced. However, I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to draw my own non-client area.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this is by using `setWindowCompositionAttribute()` method and setting it to invalid state.

Just take a look at this code: https://github.com/riverar/sample-win32-acrylicblur

Instead of setting composition attribute to

```
ACCENT_ENABLE_ACRYLICBLURBEHIND
```

set it to

```
ACCENT_INVALID_STATE
```

It will make the client area completely transparent.

Note: the `SetWindowCompositionAttribute()` is a part of undocumented API. It can be changed any time.